# Getting The complexType 'MaximumPowerType' has already been declared from an AMAZON submit call

Tags: c#, .net, xml, amazon-web-services, xsd

Amazon documentation is not clear so I am turning here for help.  Five days ago our console program that feeds various data to Amazon from our system started to toss back this error.

> mazon_Market_Place.AmazonMWSProcessor - --------- Processing Order
>   Acknowledgement Feed ----------- mazon_Market_Place.AmazonMWSProcessor
>   - ------------------------- mazon_Market_Place.AmazonMWSProcessor - Acknowledging order Axxx-yyyyyyy-5318643
>   mazon_Market_Place.AmazonMWSProcessor - -------------------------
>   Amazon_Market_Place.AmazonMWSProcessor - **Failed to validate against
>   AWS Schema
>
> The complexType 'MaximumPowerType' has already been declared.**

I am stymied as to what this means since we've done no code change to the xsd (built some time ago) nor changed the DLL.

I am wondering if any one else using Amazon AWS has gotten this error and/or what it means and how to correct.  I'll be happy to provide more information, but the log report is pretty much it.

Comment: I suspect the schema changed. Go to the URL documentation page for the schema and see if there is a revision change.

Comment: I have the same issue too. It's for about two weeks that they have changed the XSD schema. I already opened a case to the support, we have to wait.

Comment: @jdweng It should work now. Seller central support passed the case to the technical support and after some weeks they solved the issue :)